# PHP7 CLI attempts to load xdebug twice - "Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded"

Tags: php, xdebug, php-ini

After upgrading Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04, PHP CLI started complaining about xdebug:

```
$ php -v
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
PHP 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

There is only one .ini file:

```
$ ls -la /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/ | grep xdebug
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   38 Jan 19 11:41 20-xdebug.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini
```

And it's only referenced once in this output from `php -i`:

```
$ php -i | grep -i configuration
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/7.0/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
Configuration
```

And there's only one reference to xdebug in the entire directory (so it's not being included twice):

```
/etc/php/7.0$ grep -r xdebug *
mods-available/xdebug.ini:zend_extension=xdebug.so
mods-available/xdebug.ini:[xdebug]
mods-available/xdebug.ini:xdebug.remote_enable=1
mods-available/xdebug.ini:xdebug.remote_autostart=1
mods-available/xdebug.ini:xdebug.remote_port=9000
mods-available/xdebug.ini:xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

If I do `$ phpdismod xdebug` I get the following output, suggesting that it still has xdebug loaded:

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

Having done that it is no longer present in the apache config as shown by `phpinfo()`.

How do I fix this?

---

*Edit:*  Additional output as requested:

```
$ php --ini
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.0/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
```

---

```
$ cat /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini 
zend_extension=xdebug.so
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

---

As this is still an issue I have found some further detail:

Paths:

```
$ ls -la /usr/bin/php
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Apr 18  2017 /usr/bin/php -> /etc/alternatives/php
$ ls -la /etc/alternatives/php
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Feb 12 15:43 /etc/alternatives/php -> /usr/bin/php7.1
```

php:

```
$ php -v
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
PHP 7.1.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2 (cli) (built: Mar  6 2018 11:10:13) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
```

php7.1:

```
$ php7.1 -v
PHP 7.1.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2 (cli) (built: Mar  6 2018 11:10:13) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
```

The interesting thing there is that the php binary is identical to php7.1 but when called as the specific it doesn't show the already loaded message.

---

Edit, 20181006:

I still have this issue. The image below is a diff of the output of the two `php --ini` calls. As you can see, the sets of ini files loaded are the same.

[image]

They are also the same symlinked binaries:

```
ben@ben-work:~$ which php
/usr/bin/php
ben@ben-work:~$ ls -la /usr/bin/php
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 May 15 16:07 /usr/bin/php -> /etc/alternatives/php
ben@ben-work:~$ ls -la /etc/alternatives/php
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 May 30 10:13 /etc/alternatives/php -> /usr/bin/php7.1
ben@ben-work:~$ which php7.1 
/usr/bin/php7.1
```

Comment: What is the output of `php --ini` (it's better than `php -i | grep -i configuration`)? PHP must be parsing other ini files somewhere...

Comment: @LazyOne Added to the question now.

Comment: Please check all .ini for `zend_extension=` lines. You may try `extension=` to see all extensions ... but xdebug can be loaded first way only. BUT so far it must be `/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini` while you seems to have looked at `mods-available/xdebug.ini` only

Comment: One symlinks to the other.

Comment: OK .. so it's the same file. And what is the *current* content of that file?

Comment: There's only the one zend_extension line for xdebug, in `/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini`

Comment: Contents match the grep above, will add the contents to the end of the question.

Comment: So .. if you comment that out it will not load xdebug now? Unfortunately I cannot tell what `$ phpdismod xdebug` disables and where (not a Linux/Mac user myself).

Comment: phpenmod/phpdismod are modeled after apache's a2enmod/a2dismod - it creates and deletes symlinks between conf.d inside both the cli and apache2 directories and the mods-available directory, so that your config is the same for both. Running it is effectively the same as commenting out the extension line.

Comment: @bcmcfc did you figure this one out? If so, could you provide an answer, please? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @panepeter afraid not!

Comment: Seems that you had 2 xdebug.ini files to be loaded. 
_/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini_ and 
_/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini_ 
Try to comment one of them.

Comment: @MarcosRegis it's not the case or mods-available would be listed in the output of php --ini, there is only one xdebug file referenced

Answer (score 58):

I've fixed this by removing `zend_extension=xdebug.so` as I already enabled it in my docker container with `docker-php-ext-enable xdebug`. It might be that it's enabled for you as well.

Comment: I'm not using Docker.

Comment: Doesn't matter, try removing 'zend_extension=xdebug.so' from /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini.

Comment: When I remove that then xdebug doesn't get loaded at all.

Comment: Oh damn, sorry I couldn't help more. This was the problem for me as it already got loaded from somewhere else. It might be that the file is actually loaded twice for you and maybe not from the directory you searched in. I'll leave my answer as well as it might help others. Hope you manage to find the issue.

Comment: No worries, it may help someone else.

Comment: well you shuld make this accepted answer. this saved me some time. thanks

Comment: When I removed the xdebug.xo from the xdebug.ini, the problem got fixed. thanks

Comment: in my case zedn_extension line was duplicated after os upgrade

Answer (score 16):

In Arch Linux the package [xdebug](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=xdebug) generates the following configuration:

```
/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
----------
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
#xdebug.max_nesting_level=300
```

This loads twice the same `zend_extension=xdebug.so` located in `/etc/php/php.ini`

Comment: This solved my problem (Fedora Core 29, newly upgraded from FC26)
To see ini files loaded : `php --ini` => chances are there is `xdebug.ini` in the list

Comment: For me on mac using homebrew a recent upgrade edited my default php.ini settings and tacked on these new xdebug settings on top of my line including it in a previous version.

Comment: Solved the problem in Ubuntu 20, commenting out the line `zend_extension = xdebug.so`

Answer (score 11):

You need serch the zend_extension declaration in your PHP config dir, for example

```sh
grep -Hnir zend_extension /etc/php/7.2/
```

The command will tell you where you the files:line where is defined the extension, in my case:

```
/etc/php/7.2/mods-available/xdebug.ini:2:zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so
/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini:1938:; zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so
/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini:368:zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so
```

Here, both `cli/php.ini` and `apache2/php.ini` are the same config file but `mods-available/xdebug.ini` is another file with only xdebug info.

You can comment out or move the lines about xdebug in your php.ini to xdebug.ini and create a joined config under `[xdebug]` section.

Example:

```
#xdebug.ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so
xdebug.collect_params=4
xdebug.collect_vars=on
xdebug.remote_autostart=on

xdebug.var_display_max_children=128
xdebug.var_display_max_data=4086
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=10
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and solved it by removing extra line of code `zend_extension="xdebug.so"` inside the php.ini file.

The php.ini could be in `/usr/local/etc/php/` for mac users but you can run the following command to locate the php.ini file:

```
$ php -i | grep php.ini
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me (macOS High Sierra). Installed PHP using Homebrew (`brew install php@7.3`) and xdebug using pecl (`pecl install xdebug`). PHP then showed me this message. At the top of `php.ini`, the `zend_extension="xdebug.so"` was added twice.

Answer (score 4):

Debian and derivate:

I fixed it locating my php.ini, changing the `zend_extension=xdebug.so` to the old (so I guess the same would happend commenting the line) `zend_extension_ts=zdebug.so`.

Then with: `php -i | grep xdebug` there should be only one conf.d with the `zend_extension=xdebug.so`. If there were more than one delete the rest of entries.

Answer (score 3):

The cause may indeed be duplicate config files.
In my case `15-xdebug.ini` had been added by `dnf install php-pecl-xdebug3-3.0.4-1.el8.remi.8.0.x86_64`. Listing the INI files shows this:

```
ls /etc/php*/*xdebug.ini

/etc/php-cli.d/99-xdebug.ini  /etc/php.d/15-xdebug.ini  /etc/php.d/99-xdebug.ini  /etc/php-zts.d/15-xdebug.ini
```

Answer (score 1):

For users who face the same problem.

In my scenario, it was problem with **`php cli`** so every time I tried to get to php in the console, I was getting notice: **`Cannot load the ionCube PHP Loader - extension already loaded`**

I guess it will be similar to other extensions.

What I have finally done is:

```
cd /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc
grep -r "cube" .
# now I saw two files loading the .so files:
# ./php.d/01-ioncube.ini:zend_extension="/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so"
# ./php.d/pecl.ini:zend_extension="/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so"
mv php.d/pecl.ini .
```

That was it.

Answer (score 1):

this is just what i faced tried to solve this , this might help someone to figure it out .

obviously, its declared in two places, but no harm in that .
the case for me is that it is declared in the
`/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/99-xdebug.ini` ( this is the default for some reason )

and here `/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini`

by executing `php -i | grep php.ini`

you ll find that it mentions the second location only ( my assumption thatit ovverides the firt loading location )

```
❯ php -i | grep php.ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/8.1/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini
```

so i commented out the `zend_extension` line from the second ini file .

Answer (score 0):

After https://stackoverflow.com/users/2192660/javier-domenech
suggestion, that was exact my case. I've discovered two files:

/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/99-xdebug.ini.

After deleting the 99-etc, then laravel php server stopped complaining about not finding xdebug (alhough it xdebug worked fine whatsoever).

**But most important:** This has caused a real exception when trying to run phpunit test suite:
`PHPUnit\Framework\Exception: Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client`
This virtually prevented phpunit from running.

The prior action of deletion, in combination with setting
the attribute: processIsolation="true"
inside of phpunit.xml also solved this weird phpunit issue.